# Samsung Galaxy s7 id_token missing name claim

Tags: google-signin, openid-connect, samsung-galaxy

I followed [Google's guide to implemenet sign in with id tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).
It works fine on most phones, except Samsung Galaxy 7, 8, and 9 do not include a name claim, which I need for my app. Specifically,

```
idToken.getPayload().get("name")
```

returns `null`.

Are there additional steps I can take to force even Galaxy devices to return name in id_tokens?

Comment: Are you running this code on the device or on your server after sending the ID token there?

Comment: On the server after sending the id token